# What is a good word or phrase that says "work project"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm preparing my resume and I'm trying to classify the projects that I've worked on as something that was done as a part of my job or those that weren't work releated!

The one's that I've done on my own time could be listed under "Side Projects" or "Other Projects".

"Work Projects" doesn't sound so right to me. (Is it just in my head?)

Is there a good alternative to it?

PS: I'm a programmer, in case it matters.

Comment: Maybe list it under "Work Related" or "Work Related Projects"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a resume, you should only need to label the things that are not work related. I assume that everything on your resume is related to your work unless you tell me otherwise, so I think "Projects" would be fine if you really want to label the section, as long as you label the other sections appropriately (Side Projects, OpenSource Projects, etc.) "Other Projects" is too vague to be useful in my opinion.

I think "Work Projects" sounds odd because it's very close to "work product" which is kind of stiff and tends to appear in contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to them as "Professional Projects" is likely to work well. They were done as part of your profession, and that's a generally classy adjective that's not too overblown.

"Work Projects" is awkward-sounding, but I can't easily pin down exactly why. It's not *wrong*, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can say a "new development" or "new deployment" or "new milestone"

Comment: Some explanation of why you believe these are good choices would make this a better answer. I don't understand why you would choose "new" for a section title on a resume that's talking about things that happened in the past.